# References between objects

Tags: c#, reference, parent

I have been trying to figure this out for days.

What I have is three classes, let's call them City, House, Room:

```
class City
{
    List<House> Houses { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class House
{
    List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Room
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, here we have a city, which holds a lot of houses.
And the houses holds rooms.

Let's say for instance I get a room object, which has a name (and is grouped in the whole system with City->House->Room)

How would I be able to reference the City-objects Name variable from that Room object I have?

Like some magic way of doing "Room.House.City.Name"

I really hope you understand what I'm trying to ask, it's been driving me crazy for the last couple of days.

Comment: You'll have to modify your `Room` and `House` classes to contain a reference to their parent.

Comment: If the constructor for House took the containing City as a parameter then it could both add the house to the cities residences and keep a local reference in the house back to the city. Otherwise you're left with traipsing about the cities looking for the house. Similarly for the Room/House relationship. And the Dog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `House` property to your room and `City` property to your `House` like this:

```
class House
{
    List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
 }

class Room
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
}
```

And when you are adding some house and room for example:

```
    City myCity = new City();
    House myHouse = new House { City = myCity, Name = "myHome" };
    Room myRoom = new Room { House = myHouse, Name = "myRoom" };
    myHouse.Rooms = new List<Room>();    
    myHouse.Rooms.Add(myRoom);
    myCity.Houses = new List<House>();        
    myCity.Houses.Add(myHouse);
    // here you can use:
    myRoom.House.City.Name
```

But this is not so elegant and it's hard to add new Houses and Rooms.Additionally I would add some methods to make it easy for example in House class:

```
class House 
{
     public void AddRoom(Room room)
     {
        room.House = this;
        if (Rooms == null)
            Rooms = new List<Room>();
        Rooms.Add(room);
     }
}
```

And then I don't need to define a Room like this:

```
Room myRoom = new Room { House = myHouse, Name = "myRoom" };
```

Instead:

```
myHouse.AddRoom(new Room { Name = "myRoom" });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about! Thank you for showing how you go about adding the classes with each other too!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To make it possible you have to add additional, *parent-like* references into your classes:

```
class City
{
    List<House> Houses { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class House
{
    List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    City City { get; set; }
}

class Room
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    House House { get; set; }
}
```

***Update***

Because I don't think there is a chance to have House without a City and Room without a House, I would add constructors to both `House` and `Room` classes, to bind them to parents:

```
class House
{
    public House(City city)
    {
        City = city;

    }
    List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    City City { get; set; }
}

class Room
{
    public Room(House house)
    {
        House = house;
    }
    string Name { get; set; }
    House House { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change your classes to contain a reference to their parent e.g.

```
class Room
{
    House House { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class House
{
    List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    City City { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can't navigate from a property to it's container. This is only possible if you also have properties like House in the Room object and if you make sure that when you assign a  Room the a House, you also set the House property in your Room.

However, you can use some LINQ to get the City Name, like this:

```
var cityWithSomeRoom = cities.Where(c = > c.Houses.Contains(h => h.Rooms.Contains(r => r.ReferenceEquals(someRoom))).FirstOrDefault();
cityWithSomeRoom.Name ; // this is your name
```

someRoom is the Room instance that you want to find out in which city resides. Also, make sure that you don't add the same room object to multiple houses, because ReferenceEquals will find many candidates.

Comment: possible System.NullReferenceException in this case

Comment: Make sure that all your cities have Houses set to a list of houses and that all your houses have Rooms. You can add in the constructor of the City and House object something like: this.Houses = new List<Houses>() to make sure that if you don't have any House in that city, the property is an empty list instead of a null object. Do the same for Rooms list in House object.